# Match two tables summarized by different dimensions, Grand total for each tables are Equal

Tags: sql, algorithm

Here is table T1 Orders, Lines and Sales are summed by Location, Each order can have one or more lines. Product description (desc1) and optional product description (desc2) are unknown.

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+--------+-------+-------------+
| PK | Desc 1 | Desc 2 | Location | Orders | Lines | Sales Total |
+----+--------+--------+----------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | ?      | ?      | Site 1   |      3 |    60 |      187107 |
|  2 | ?      | ?      | Site 1   |      4 |    40 |      146851 |
|  3 | ?      | ?      | Site 2   |      8 |    62 |      152813 |
|  4 | ?      | ?      | Site 3   |      1 |    11 |       38970 |
+----+--------+--------+----------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Here is table T2, Orders, Lines and Sales are summed by Description 1 & 2 product will always have description 1 an sometimes have description 2. Location is unknown.

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+--------+-------+-------------+
| PK | Desc 1 |   Desc 2   | Location | Orders | Lines | Sales Total |
+----+--------+------------+----------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |  29570 |            | ?        |      4 |    74 |      245249 |
|  2 |  29572 |       9419 | ?        |      1 |     2 |        6796 |
|  3 |  29633 |       9419 | ?        |      1 |     2 |        7169 |
|  4 |  29633 |       9427 | ?        |      1 |    18 |       65941 |
|  5 |  29653 |       9419 | ?        |      2 |    40 |       94770 |
|  6 |  29654 |            | ?        |      1 |     6 |       13343 |
|  7 |  29654 |       9419 | ?        |      1 |     4 |       10150 |
|  8 |  29662 |            | ?        |      1 |     1 |        2463 |
|  9 |  29663 |       9419 | ?        |      1 |     7 |       18122 |
| 10 |  29690 |            | ?        |      2 |    12 |       36874 |
| 11 |   2989 |            | ?        |      1 |     7 |       24864 |
+----+--------+------------+----------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

The total sum of Orders, Lines and Sales for each table are equal. What I am trying to do is use these tables to come up with a unified table where both product description desc1 and desc2 are known. Is there a way to do this in SQL? I have had some luck with smaller tables since I know that a site from T1 with 1 order cannot match up with any descriptions from T2 with 1 order as that would leave 0 orders left over. So in these tables for example we know that PK 4 from T1 matches with a portion of PK5 from T2 because when we try to subtract PK4 in T1  from PK 1 in T2 it leaves us with 63 lines, more that could fit in any of the leftover sites.  Basically I've been trying to solve this like a sodoku puzzle but I thought that I could do something in SQL that would be faster and more elegant.  I have looked into cross joins that make a cartesian product of both tables but that doesn't seem to be working as some of the sites will need to be broken up to match up with the rows of the product descriptions.  I can make an algorithm to spot the obvious matches to get it to the point where I could just do every permutation of products, but perhaps I'm overthinking it and there is an easier way.

This is a tricky one, but I'm sure someone has run into this problem before, I can't find how they solved it though.

Comment: I don't see how you would be able to match these properly - there is no common relation. Isn't there "raw data" that can be used, that make up these two tables?

Comment: "So in these tables for example we know that PK 4 from T1 matches with a portion of PK5 from T2 because when we try to subtract PK4 in T1 from PK 1 in T2 it leaves us with 63 lines, more that could fit in any of the leftover sites." If PK5 in T2 has more than one site associated with it, then so too could PK1 in T2 (presumably). Given that subtracting PK4 in T1 from PK 1 in T2 leaves 3 orders and 63 lines, even though 63 lines exceeds what's possible for any single location, how do you conclude that it can't be a combination of orders from other sites? What's the logic?

Comment: What does PK stand for and how does it relate to the other labels in the table header?